# Stuck mouse pointer on high CPU usage since upgrade to Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: mouse, 19.10

I recently upgraded my laptop from Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.10. Since upgrade the mouse pointer always gets stuck when there is high CPU usage. The issue does not relate to the device (occurs with both touchpad and mouse).

Is this behaviour known? 
Is there a known solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem went away after upgrading to ubuntu 20.04